# how to have a chart with no spline and no interpolation in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for a very basic kind of chart but I don't find it in the list, some sort of mix between 'columns' and 'line'. No interpolation/staircase.

Just imagine I am plotting the number of people in a room over time. I have points (t1, 10), (t2, 5), (t3, 15) where t1, t2, t3 are dates. I don't want the charts to linearly interpolate between 10 and 5 and between 5 and 15. I want something horizontal.

[image: people]

I was thinking of doing (t1, 10), (t2-epsilon, 10), (t2, 5), (t3-epsilon, 5), (t3, 15) but this is pretty dirty, I want a simple chart.

Columns look like they could do the job but I don't feel good about them.

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: An image would indeed be nice :) So, do you just want a symbol drawn at those coordinates and no line between the points, or do you want a straight line (no stairs, no curve/spline) from t1 to t2 and so on?

Comment: not just symbols but some stairs. (imagine what the points with 'epsilon' would help draw). I will try to figure out how to upload an image at the same time

Comment: see pic :)  obviously I need to be better at english descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is also possible for Highcharts Line chart. You can find reference here:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/line-chart

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        step: 'left' // or 'center' or 'right'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks quite like High**stock**s step-line chart:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/step-line

Comment: thanks I didn't really look at highstocks, I don't know why these are 2 separated libraries